# Docker desktop kubernetes performance

Tags: kubernetes, docker-desktop, ubuntu-22.04

I have 18 deployments with replicas = 2 each so it's like 36 pods. I run a `kubectl scale --current-replicas=2 --replicas=2 deployment/user` for each deployment but even then when I run any command it gives an error sometimes like this: `Unable to connect to the server: net/http: TLS handshake timeout`

follow my deployments:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-gateway
  labels:
    app: my-gateway
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: my-gateway
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: my-gateway
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-gateway
        image: rafaelribeirosouza86/shopping:api-gateway
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 31534
          protocol: TCP
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-adm-contact
  labels:
    app: my-adm-contact
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: my-adm-contact
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: my-adm-contact
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-adm-contact
        image: rafaelribeirosouza86/shopping:my-adm-contact
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 30001
          protocol: TCP
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred


---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: category-busca
  labels:
    app: category-busca
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: category-busca
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: category-busca
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: category-busca
        image: rafaelribeirosouza86/shopping:category-busca
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 31534
          protocol: TCP
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: category-menu
  labels:
    app: category-menu
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: category-menu
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: category-menu
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: category-menu
        image: rafaelribeirosouza86/shopping:category-menu
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 31529
          protocol: TCP
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: category-product
  labels:
    app: category-product
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: category-product
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: category-product
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: category-product
        image: rafaelribeirosouza86/shopping:category-product
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 31527
          protocol: TCP
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: location
  labels:
    app: location
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: location
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: location
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: location
        image: rafaelribeirosouza86/shopping:location
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 31524
          protocol: TCP
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: product-star
  labels:
    app: product-star
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: product-star
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: product-star
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: product-star
        image: rafaelribeirosouza86/shopping:product-star
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 31519
          protocol: TCP
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: product-get-star
  labels:
    app: product-get-star
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: product-get-star
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: product-get-star
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: product-get-star
        image: rafaelribeirosouza86/shopping:product-get-star
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 31522
          protocol: TCP
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: product-single
  labels:
    app: product-single
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: product-single
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: product-single
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: product-single
        image: rafaelribeirosouza86/shopping:product-single
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 31523
          protocol: TCP
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred


---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: purchase-create
  labels:
    app: purchase-create
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: purchase-create
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: purchase-create
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: purchase-create
        image: rafaelribeirosouza86/shopping:purchase-create
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 31521
          protocol: TCP
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: purchase-get
  labels:
    app: purchase-get
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: purchase-get
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: purchase-get
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: purchase-get
        image: rafaelribeirosouza86/shopping:purchase-get
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 31518
          protocol: TCP
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred


---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: purchase-get-car
  labels:
    app: purchase-get-car
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: purchase-get-car
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: purchase-get-car
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: purchase-get-car
        image: rafaelribeirosouza86/shopping:purchase-get-car
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 31520
          protocol: TCP
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: user
  labels:
    app: user
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: user
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: user
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: user
        image: rafaelribeirosouza86/shopping:user
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 31533
          protocol: TCP
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: user-create
  labels:
    app: user-create
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: user-create
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: user-create
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: user-create
        image: rafaelribeirosouza86/shopping:user-create
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 31531
          protocol: TCP
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: user-login
  labels:
    app: user-login
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: user-login
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: user-login
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: user-login
        image: rafaelribeirosouza86/shopping:user-login
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 31532
          protocol: TCP
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred


---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: user-senha
  labels:
    app: user-senha
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: user-senha
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: user-senha
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: user-senha
        image: rafaelribeirosouza86/shopping:user-senha
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 31526
          protocol: TCP
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: user-update
  labels:
    app: user-update
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: user-update
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: user-update
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: user-update
        image: rafaelribeirosouza86/shopping:user-update
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 31530
          protocol: TCP
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred
```

I'm using kubernetes from docker desktop and I'm trying to scale my application.

Is there any way to improve the performance of my api?

Comment: Can you try if some answer from this question fits your use case ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59958274/unable-to-connect-to-the-server-net-http-tls-handshake-timeout

Comment: Also can you share the deployment manifest ?

Comment: I would suggest you to add resource limit and request for all these deployment so that they do not over consume the resources.

Comment: `resources:
      requests:
        memory: "64Mi"
        cpu: "250m"
      limits:
        memory: "128Mi"
        cpu: "500m"`like this code?

Comment: yes it ensures that application uses only resources allocated to the app

Comment: I'm using hap I found a good solution for docker kubernetes. the command: `kubectl autoscale deployment category-search --cpu-percent=4 --min=1 --max=5`