# Minikube start command taking long time

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

Going through blogs/official sites, I installed kubectl and minikube. After successful installation of both, I executed the following command.

```
minikube start --driver=hyperv
```

After executing the above command I am struck and the process is not completed at all as mentioned below screenshot.
[image]

The process has been running in step:4 (Updating the running hyperv "minikube" VM...) for more than 30 minutes.

Please help me to resolve this as I just started learning Kubernetes.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can help (from here [Minikube is slow and unresponsive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56327843/minikube-is-slow-and-unresponsive)):

**1)** Debugging issues with minikube by adding `-v` flag and set debug level (0, 1, 2, 3, 7).

As example: `minikube start --v=1` to set outbut to INFO level.
More detailed information [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/master/docs/debugging.md)

**2)** Use logs command `minikube logs`

**3)** Because Minikube is working on Virtual Machine sometimes is better to delete minikube and start it again (It helped in this case).

```
minikube delete
minikube start
```

**4)** It might get slow due to lack of resources.

Minikube as default is using 2048MB of memory and 2 CPUs. More details about this can be fund [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/232080ae0cbcf9cb9a388eb76cc11cf6884e19c0/pkg/minikube/constants/constants.go#L97)
In addition, you can enforce Minikue to create more using command `minikube start --cpus 4 --memory 8192`